# window?.subviews[1] app is crashing in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I'm working on Picture in Picture out functionality for the calling feature where requirement to get he window subview

I used this code to get it 
`transitionView = AppDelegate.shared.window?.subviews[1] ?? self.view`
it working on less that iOS 13 versions 
But the sane code is crashing in iOS 13

Here is my complete function

```
func showPictureInPictureMode(){
    transitionView = AppDelegate.shared.window?.subviews[1] ?? self.view
    transitionView?.frame = CGRect(x: screenWidth - width - 13, y: 80, width: width, height: height)
    transitionView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    transitionView?.clipsToBounds = true
    transitionView?.addGestureRecognizer(transitionPanGesture)
    transitionView?.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.07843137255, green: 0.07843137255, blue: 0.07843137255, alpha: 1)
    transitionView?.borderWidth = 1
    self.view.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.07843137255, green: 0.07843137255, blue: 0.07843137255, alpha: 1)
    self.view.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    self.view.clipsToBounds = false
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    self.isPictureInPicture = true
    self.toolbar.isHidden = true
    self.pictureModeButton.isHidden = true
    self.timeLabel.isHidden = true

    self.opponentsCollectionView.reloadData()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .reloadButtonState, object: nil)
}
```

Could some one help to resolve the issue.

Thanks In advance

Comment: because ios 13 has sceneDelegate

Comment: Thanks, @jawadAli for your prompt answer, could you let me what I have to correct here

Comment: what are you getting from window ?

Comment: @jawadAli, A UIView having a Picture in Picture mode feature, but its throwing index out if bound exception, if tried access 0th index it returns black screen to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution 
Simply I changed the UIViewController presentation Style `.defualt` to `.overFullScreen`

Like this :

```
pipVC.ModalPresentationStyle = . overFullScreen
```

The reason was, not getting UILayoutContainerView while presenting the screen in the default style.

Its resolved to change the mode.